# Biodiversity through radiation

Tags: biology, space, aliens, mutation

I was wanting to make a species on an alien planet that reproduce purely asexualy, and their star produces enough radiation to cause common mutations among the children to cause something similar to biodiversity. Would this be possible?

Comment: It looks like you're soliciting opinions and asking for us to elaborate on any possible problem or benefits of your idea. That's far too broad and subjective to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Sorry if it looked that way, I'm just looking for yes/no answers here.

Comment: To do that someone would need to determine the collection of problems caused by your idea, and all the benefits and then compare the count of each. How do you realistically expect us to be able do all that as something that isn't simply just us sharing our opinion?

Comment: Okay, sorry about the trouble. I think I changed it to something that fit the standards now.

Comment: Given that all the diverse life on earth evolved from asexual reproduction without a highly radioactive star what makes you think that things would be any different if there were more sources for genetic variation?

Comment: I don't know. I just thought it might be neat to have that kind of concept. Also, you say the words "diverse life on earth", but this is an alien species with a vastly different environment from our own, so many species will evolve different characteristics than Earth life. I had an idea, thought about it for a moment, then threw it in here.

Comment: Radiation is a poor source of mutation. It tends to cause easy to correct/repair  damage. Mutagenic compounds or even just elevated temperatures are more consistent sources of mutation.  Mix and match of genetic sequences like bacteria tend to do would also be more common source of mutation.

Comment: Hello @Justalittlemischievous, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. I believe your idea is well enough defined that an answer is possible, so I answered it. Thank you for listening to comments discussing weaknesses in your question and addressing those weaknesses! The Stack does have rules governing acceptable questions, which you can find by reading the [tour] and, at minimum, the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. We look forward to working with you as you build new worlds!

Comment: In response to the VTC, this isn't actually a matter of opinion. The effects of radiation on reproductive mutations is a heavily studied field. For most multicellular organisms, a level of radiation that mutates offspring will kill the organism before they reach reproductive age.

Comment: It seems that the response of the individuals to environmental conditions (like radiation) has a much harder impact on biodiversity than conditions themselves. In the open, individuals that develop repair mechanisms (like melanin) have a higher chance of survival, those who dwell in forests or caves will do not undergo this selection. // Irradiation fields will not necessarily produce genomes that will survive in the wild. Under hard radiation and natural selection, most likely those individuals will prosper that have the lowest demands (and may develop into radiation-hardened flora).

Answer (score 22):

From a high level point of view, yes, it possible.

In the past, before genetic engineering techniques were available, a way of producing new types of plants was to use irradiation fields: a radioactive material was placed at the center of a field and all around it [plants were grown](https://99percentinvisible.org/episode/atom-garden-eden/), continuously exposed to the radiation.

> The United States military began to research not only on how make atomic bombs, but what their effects might be after detonation. So-called “gamma gardens” in places like Brookhaven National Labs in New York aimed to discover the effects of chronic exposure to gamma rays on plants. Within a few years, they went from just analyzing the effects of radiation to researching whether gamma radiation could actually induce beneficial mutations.
>
> Some of these gamma gardens were huge (up to five acres or more) and were generally laid out as large circles with crops planted in concentric rings. Within the garden, species were separated into a series of pie-shaped wedges. In the center of the field, a pole containing a radioactive isotope (usually cobalt-60) would shower the field with gamma radiation for about 20 hours a day. When it was time for researchers to go in and see the results, they would remotely lower the source into an underground bunker made of concrete or lead, step inside the field’s high fence, and inspect the plants arrayed around the center. The plants closest to the source were usually dead or stunted or gnarled with tumors. The plants around the edges generally looked normal but would be evaluated by the scientists to see if they had any beneficial mutations.
>
> [image]
>
> [...] Because of radiation breeding experiments, there are over 2000 plant varieties that have been released into the global food system. These include a strain of wheat in Italy, varieties of rice throughout Asia, certain pears in Japan, and a breed of sunflower in the United States, just to name a few. The Rio Star grapefruit also came about because of radiation breeding experiments and now accounts for about 75% of the grapefruit grown in Texas.

The same process can apply to organisms reproducing in an asexual way. It actually already happens with random mutations in bacteria and other unicellular organisms, caused by environmental radiation or other agents.

What makes it more difficult for a multicellular organism is that the mutation of a single cell would hardly have consequences on the whole organism, and having the same mutation on all the cells is highly unlikely. This is not a problem with sexual reproduction because the gamete is a single cell from which the whole organism will be derived.

Therefore, if you dive deeper in the fine writings, it's very unlikely that a multicellular organism, reproducing in an asexual way, can get any functioning functional change by exposure to radiation.

Addendum:

I have just found this [article](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.ade2537?cookieSet=1) where the authors have examined the genetics of the stray dogs living in the exclusion zone in Chernobyl, a highly radioactive environment:

> Chernobyl dogs are genetically distinct from other free-breeding and purebred dog populations.
>
> [...]
>
> Similarity to other free-breeding dog populations, versus purebred dog populations, is indicative of the Chernobyl dogs’ origin in the CEZ region. For example, elevated haplotype sharing with purebred populations might suggest that the original population has been largely replaced by modern pet dogs, leading to intrinsically lower genomic variation from which to distinguish mutations related to radiation exposure. However, this would also make the Chernobyl dogs less than ideal candidates for future genomic studies into cumulative DNA damage and for finding genetic variants associated with population survival and propagation. It is formally possible that some of the early genetic scars present in dogs living in the region immediately after the explosion that have been lost in modern populations are now replaced by large signatures of purebred ancestry. However, we demonstrate that this is unlikely.

Comment: The difficulty in applying this result to this question, is that the percentage of the total population exposed to the radiation was negligible.  Even if the entirety of the exposed group was killed or received a negative mutation, it had no effect on the genetic health of the general population.   Then, once a positive mutation arrived, it was removed from the radiation, so was then able to grow without being further mutated or killed by it.

Comment: Multicellular organisms may reproduce asexually via unicellular reproductive bodies like spores. Depending on the method of reproduction, mutations in a single cell could be passed on to a descendant who is wholly derived from that genome.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Effect_of_Gamma_Rays_on_Man-in-the-Moon_Marigolds

Comment: Fascinating piece of history, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**If you're looking for suspension of disbelief, yes**

Over the decades, a [considerable number of studies were done concerning plants and insects surviving the Tunguska meteor impact](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0311337). Theories about genetic anomalies have been proffered, substantiated, rejected, and debated. There is still so much we don't understand about that event that, from this perspective and for the purpose of suspension of disbelief, yes, you could use the argument of radiation to rationalize the idea of asexual reproduction and genetic diversity.

**However, if we stick too closely to science, radiation is pretty much always universally bad**

Part of the ongoing debate about the consequences of the Tunguska Event concerns the influence of radiation. If you read the article from that link, above, you'll learn that genetic anomalies also occurred along the path of the incoming object (called the Tunguska Space Body or TSB because we don't actually know what it was — other than we're pretty sure it wasn't an alien space ship). The problem is there was no evidence of radiation along that path, only at the impact site.

This supports a basic maxim about radiation: it's usually bad. It's usually very bad.

> Ionizing radiation has sufficient energy to affect the atoms in living cells and thereby damage their genetic material (DNA). Fortunately, the cells in our bodies are extremely efficient at repairing this damage. However, if the damage is not repaired correctly, a cell may die or eventually become cancerous. ([Source](https://www.epa.gov/radiation/radiation-health-effects))

Additionally...

> How Radiation Affects Your Body:
>
> - Radiation can damage the DNA in our cells.
> - High doses of radiation can cause Acute Radiation Syndrome (ARS) or Cutaneous Radiation Injuries (CRI).
> - High doses of radiation could also lead to cancer later in life. ([Source](https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/radiation/health.html))

Radiation rarely (if ever) leads to beneficial mutation (aka, Spider-Man). It's destructive. Radiation is energy, and like all energy, when too much of it is applied to something susceptible to it, the result is the destruction of the susceptible something.

**But that doesn't mean you're not moving toward a good idea, let's look to how asexual life deals with the problem today**

Let me introduce you to horizontal gene transfer:

> When prokaryotes and eukaryotes reproduce asexually, they transfer a nearly identical copy of their genetic material to their offspring through vertical gene transfer. Although asexual reproduction produces more offspring more quickly, any benefits of diversity among those offspring are lost. How then do organisms whose dominant reproductive mode is asexual create genetic diversity? In prokaryotes, horizontal gene transfer (HGT), the introduction of genetic material from one organism to another organism within the same generation, is an important way to introduce genetic diversity. HGT allows even distantly related species to share genes, influencing their phenotypes. It is thought that HGT is more prevalent in prokaryotes but that only a small fraction of the prokaryotic genome may be transferred by this type of transfer at any one time. As the phenomenon is investigated more thoroughly, it may be revealed to be even more common. ***Many scientists believe that HGT and mutation are significant sources of genetic variation, the raw material for the process of natural selection, in prokaryotes.*** Although HGT is more common among evolutionarily related organisms, it may occur between any two species that live together in a natural community.
>
> HGT in prokaryotes is known to occur by the three primary mechanisms...
>
> 1. Transformation: naked DNA is taken up from the environment
> 2. Transduction: genes are transferred between cells in a virus (see The Viral Life Cycle)
> 3. Conjugation: use of a hollow tube called a conjugation pilus to transfer genes between cells ([Source](https://geo.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/GEL_098-16%3A_Geobiology_(Sumner)/Text/3%3A_Genes_to_Enzymes/How_Asexual_Prokaryotes_Achieve_Genetic_Diversity), emphasis mine)

You'll notice from my emphasis in the above quote that HGT *and* mutation are believed to be the primary sources of genetic diversity in prokaryotes. But that mutation is biological mutation (e.g., a change in hair color), not radiation mutation (e.g., tumors).

**Conclusion**

1. There is nothing stopping you from using radiation as the rationalization for genetic diversity in your alien population. The wonderful thing about alien populations is that they don't need to conform to what we know is true *for Earth.* Humans are wonderfully adept at suspending their disbelief.
2. But, if you're looking for scientifically supportable solutions, you can't use radiation. In that case I would consider researching Horizontal Gene Transfer and creating an HGT-based explanation that makes sense for your creatures.

Answer (score 3):

Mutation from radiation is rarely passed on to offspring. Most mutation occurs to parts of a person's body that aren't involved in reproduction, so it reduces survivability.

It shouldn't surprise you that application of radiation results in traits that harden the creature against radiation (like hair or melamine). The requirement to defend against radiation takes biological energy to produce, so the effect is to make the creature less fit for other purposes, like finding food or defending itself against predators. This extra requirement can actually slow the speed of evolutionary development.

Answer (score 2):

**Unnecesary**

No one can tell you if this is possible. We know zilch about extraterrestrial life.*

But it is unnecessary. Just declare the species mutates faster than life on Earth.

Perhaps due to radiation as you say.

Perhaps due to a much smaller *genome* that is more sensitive to mutations of a small number of *base pairs*. [Small genomes mean faster evolution.](https://www.google.com/search?q=small+genome+evolve+faster&client=ubuntu&hs=wJp&channel=fs&ei=YMUAZLrfG8ulgAaM16zYDA&ved=0ahUKEwi6j-ydzL39AhXLEsAKHYwrC8sQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=small+genome+evolve+faster&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyCAghEBYQHhAdOgoIABBHENYEELADOgUILhCRAjoICC4Q1AIQkQI6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOg4ILhDHARCxAxDRAxCABDoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAgAELEDEIMBOhQILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAxDUAjoICAAQgAQQsQM6BAguEEM6BQgAEJECOgQIABBDOgcILhDUAhBDOgUIABCABDoHCAAQsQMQQzoFCC4QgAQ6BAgAEAM6CAguEIAEELEDOgcIABCABBAKOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQHhAPOgsIABAWEB4QDxDxBDoICAAQFhAeEAo6BQgAEIYDOgoIIRAWEB4QDxAdOgcIIRCgARAKSgQIQRgAUJgEWPkfYP8gaAFwAXgAgAFWiAGgDJIBAjI2mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Perhaps the life simply *evolved* this way to be less precise when copying *DNA*.

Perhaps the fast mutation is due to something about the creature's biology being completely unlike that on Earth.

---

*Does it being rare count?

Answer (score 1):

DNA is a lot more complicated than what it seems. Every sequence does not contain only the bases that encode a trait, but also the ones that control how the trait is copied to RNA and the how it is expressed.  During sexual reproduction usually entire sequences are swapped when the chromosomes are mixed. Mutations that damage the decoding process are rare.

Random mutations by radiations are a lot more likely to affect the way DNA is copied and decoded. Deformities or individuals unable to cope with the environment would be a lot more frequent. Biodiversity through radiation could still be possible, but only with a very high rate of births and deaths together with a ruthless selection. So, what you will need is a high birth rate and a Spartan attitude.

Answer (score 1):

You can have biodiversity without mutations. All it takes set of genes that are switched on or off in the offspring that are set on or off differently from the parent. Even in humans, there is such mechanism, [epigenetics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics).

Also environmental factors can modify genetic expression. This is how bee queens grow differently from workers. [They get a bit different food](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_jelly), and they grow into a bit different individual.

Also, plants can exhibit very different phenotype even if they are clones. You cannot find two identical oaks. Environment directs their growth, and the trunk, roots, branches etc. come out all different.

Yoy can xtrapolate from these examples and make your alien species exhibit different characteristics on each individual.

Answer (score 0):

On highly complex and DNA some random modifications as caused by radiation will most likely just "damage" it, meaning the likelihood that something "good" will happen is much lower than something "bad" will happen.

So on the long run it *may* increase diversity, but on the short run, it will probably just reduce the population.
Maybe the surviving population will just be the kind that hides in caves to avoid radiation.

Also diversity is no advantage if it does not bring a benefit to the individual.

Answer (score 0):

In the hundred years following the publication of "Origin of Species", repeated attempts were made to reconcile the "observed" age of the earth with the "observed" rate of evolution. These attempts consisted of (1) repeated extension of the "known" age of the earth, and (2) various theories about accelerated speciation.

Ultimately, "naive Darwinism" was replaced by the "modern consensus" which includes speciation by non-Darwinian mechanisms, because (1) further study of the fossil record caused changes in the understanding of evolution, and (2) the various theories of accelerated "speciation by natural selection" were not sufficient to meet the requirements of the known age of the earth.

In the 1950's, radiation enhanced variation was the go-to theory for matching the "Theory of Evolution" to the "Known Age of the Earth". Consequently, it got a lot of scientific research and popular exposure. Cultural references were movies about "kids with powers" (as the result of radiation) and of course "Spider Man" -- bitten by a radio-active spider.

The theory failed on investigation. Radiation does not cause enough enhanced variation to enable "selection on variation" to account for the origin of species. The next major attempt to reconcile TOE and "known age of the Earth" was the "population bottlenecks" theory. That has aged a lot better than the "radiation" theory.

What this has left us with is the situation where "radiation to cause common mutations" is still "popular science". It's just not "science" anymore.